# Dart-Editor: Dart not invoked?

Tags: dart, chromium, dart-editor, dartium

For some reason i don't know, my DartEditor suddenly does not run the dart code anymore when i run an HTML file in Dartium. Nothing happends on chromium and nothing is displayed in the console output.

Either:

- Chromium loads everything instantely
- Chromium load the html but still loads indifenitely

I have already:

- checked that the build was successfull
- restarted DartEditor many times
- made sure to remove all breakpoints
- specified into the .html file which .dart to load
- tried to run the simpliest dart code (a single print() in the main),

The only related topic ([Simple Dart Web Component Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158809/simple-dart-web-component-not-working)) does not resolve my problem.
Any help would be much apreciated, thank you.

Comment: I guess this is because Dartium is expired. Is you Dart version up-to-date? If not open DartEditors configuration and enable update checks.

Comment: My Dart version is up-to-date. This problem happened to me randomly twice and the only -brutal- fix i found was to reinstall Dart-Editior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fix I found was to reinstall completely the Dart-Editor with its SDK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes dart does something similar and normally there are errors on the bindings within my html. Even fixing that error, it seems that dartium still not wanting to load my page (sometimes I even get 404 index.html not found).

My solution is to run an example project with no errors that I know it couldn't crash, for some reasons that unblocks dartium for the main project too.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess in this case killing `pub serve` usually fixes the issue. If you use WebStorm there is a `Pub Serve` tool window with a red `Stop Pub Serve` button. Webstorm automatically starts `pub serve` again when required.  `Pub Service` reveals some errors only after a fresh restart while otherwise it just doesn't server anything to the browser.